# ConvertFrom-Json "add" null items to array

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-5.0

I am working with a file that has a JSON string in it.

```
{
    "ConfigurationItems": [{
        "ActiveDirectory": [{
                "Users": [
                    { "FirstName": "U1", "LastName": "L1", "Department": "D1", "UserName": "UN1" },
                    { "FirstName": "U2", "LastName": "L2", "Department": "D2", "UserName": "UN2" },
                    { "FirstName": "U3", "LastName": "L3", "Department": "D3", "UserName": "UN3" },
                    { "FirstName": "U4", "LastName": "L4", "Department": "D4", "UserName": "UN4" },
                    { "FirstName": "U5", "LastName": "L5", "Department": "D5", "UserName": "UN5" }
                ]
            },
            {
                "Groups": [
                    { "Name": "G1", "Scope": "Global" },
                    { "Name": "G2", "Scope": "Global" },
                    { "Name": "G3", "Scope": "Global" }
                ]
            },
            {
                "OU": [
                    { "Name": "N1" },
                    { "Name": "N2" },
                    { "Name": "N3" }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }]
}
```

I assign this to a variable by doing the following:

```
$t = Get-content -path $pathtoJSON -raw | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Now comes the part I cannot explain if I get the count of Users it returns 7

```
$t.ConfigurationItems.ActiveDirectory.Users.Count
```

The main issue is when I iterate through this, I will always end up with two `$null` items in my loop, which throws off my code. How do I ensure I get the correct count from `ConvertFrom-Json`. For the time being I have worked around this by checking if my array item is not `$null`

I am using PS 5.1 for this.

Comment: Two other items in `$t.ConfigurationItems[0].ActiveDirectory` array do not have `Users` property, thus them return `$null` or throw exception if in strict mode (`Set-StrictMode -Version 2`).

Comment: Is there a better way of doing this. This is to be used as a template to  building pester tests ?

Comment: @APJ What do you mean by "better way" - the `ConfigurationItems` and `ActiveDirectory` entries are arrays, you'll have to treat them as such

Comment: if i loop through the users array I only want to return the 5 item in it not 7. My JSON is not that great, but  I think I have it that `ActiviteDirectory` has 3 child arrays. And `Users` being item 0 of `ActiveDirectory` has 5 child Items. Not sure why `Groups` and `OU`  are coming into play at the `Users` level

Comment: Ok, I think I figure out my issue. I am referencing my JSON variable as follows `$t.ConfigurationItems.ActiveDirectory.Users.count` which returns 7. Instead I should be doing it as follows `$t.ConfigurationItems[0].ActiveDirectory[0].Users.count` this returns the desired count of 5.